# building electron using forge gives an error

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

i want to build this electron app but it gives me an error when i type `npm run make`  the error: `It looks like you are missing some dependencies you need to get Electron running. Make sure you have git installed and Node.js version >= 14.17.5` i installed git from https://git-scm.com/download/win but still the same problem this is the package.JSON file:

```
    "name": "OverStat",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "main.js",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.4",
        "electron": "^22.0.0",
        "electron-reloader": "^1.2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "make": "electron-forge make"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "electron-builder": "^23.6.0"
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

i restarted  VS code and now this is happening

```
✔ Checking your system
✔ Loading configuration
✖ Resolving make targets
  › Could not find any make targets configured for the "win32" platform.
◼ Running package command
◼ Running preMake hook
◼ Making distributables
◼ Running postMake hook

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Could not find any make targets configured for the "win32" platform.
at Task.task (D:\projects\electron learning\node_modules\@electron-forge\core\dist\api\make.js:122:27)
    at Task.run (D:\projects\electron learning\node_modules\listr2\dist\index.cjs:978:35)
```

---

### Edit 2

---

this is the forge.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {},
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Please share your forge config as well.

Comment: i edited the post have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I've added this in package.json inside the `"makers"` and it just worked:

```
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "electron_quick_start"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
```